# Information about the secondary cell when using android?

Tags: android, telephony, telecommunication, 5g

I wonder how I can get information about the secondary NR cell when connected to NSA 5G? Is there currently existing any method in android that can access and retrieve the information about the secondary cell? Now I only retrieve information about the primary LTE cell.

I added 5G capabilities to the application to detect NSA 5G: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/features/5g.

One can read about the different scenarios in 5G: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/5g-nsa

Can I find information about the secondary NR cell one is connected to. Is there any way of doing this yet?

Comment: Any updated?, I have the same problem too.